# Download a file to a particular folder python

Tags: python, file, download, directory, urllib2

I can download a file from `URL` the following way.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.someurl.com/file.pdf")
html = response.read()
```

One way I can think of is open this file as binary and then resave it to the differnet folder I want to save

but is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

```
import urllib
linkToFile = "http://www.someurl.com/file.pdf"
localDestination = "/home/user/local/path/to/file.pdf"
resultFilePath, responseHeaders = urllib.urlretrieve(linkToFile, localDestination)
```

**UPD from 2023:** Although **urlretrieve** is still available as [urllib.request.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) it is reported to be in danger of deprecations. I can't find any built-in solution with the same interface and the best solution I could offer for those who want to keep their code up-to-date is to download file with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) lib
and then to dump it to file:

```
import requests

linkToFile = "http://www.someurl.com/best_file.pdf"
localDestination = "/home/user/path/to/file.pdf"

response = requests.get(linkToFile)

# just in case of any problem
response.raise_for_status()

with open(localDestination, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

If you are not sure about the size of the file, you could download it in chunks:

```
import requests

linkToFile = "http://www.someurl.com/file.pdf"
localDestination = "/home/user/local/path/to/file.pdf"

# add streamming option for get
response = requests.get(linkToFile, stream=True)

response.raise_for_status()

#
with open(localDestination, 'wb') as file:
    # you could set an arbitrary chunk size
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):  
        file.write(chunk)
```

Or you could use [wget](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) as suggested in the answer below (but this lib seems to have no updates since 2015):

```
import wget

url = "http://someurl.com/file.pdf"
wget.download(url, '/path/to/file.pdf')
```

Comment: Why do I have to specify file name in local destination?

Comment: What if I want it to be the same file name?

Comment: @Ank The documentation I linked to in my answer says _"The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name)"_. So if you want to keep the file name, you will have to analyze linkToFile by yourself to extract the filename, for example with [urlparse module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urlparse) and [os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.basename#os.path.basename) like that: **fileName = os.path.basename(urlparse.urlparse(linkToFile).path)**.

Comment: As of May 2023, the `urllib` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface) identifies `urllib.urlretrieve` as a legacy interface likely to be deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the python module `wget` for downloading the file. Here is a sample code

```
import wget
url = 'http://www.example.com/foo.zip'
path = 'path/to/destination'
wget.download(url,out = path)
```