# Specify a download path usig wget module in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to download files from a site using the `wget module`.
The code is really simple:

```
image = 'linkoftheimage'

wget.download(image)
```

This works fine, but it saves the file in the folder with the python script. My goal is to download it in a different folder, but I can't find a way to specify it.
I tried a different approach with `os module` .

```
os.system(f'wget -O {directory} {image}')
```

This metod gives me an error: `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token` `('

So I tried another method:

```
with open(f'{directory}/photo %s.jpg' %a,'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(image)
```

This also didn't worked out.

Does anyone have an idea on how could I solve this?

Comment: there are several libraries called `wget` which one are you using?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867437/download-a-file-to-a-particular-folder-python

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/wget/

Comment: Also I'd suggest to use `requests` or `urllib` modules instead

Comment: Did you read the page you show us ? `download(url, out, bar) contains out parameter` use `out` parameter

Comment: Your `os.system` call should work; the error suggests that one of the variables contains a character which needs to be quoted. Like the `os.system` documentatron already tells you, a better solution  is to use e.g. `subprocess.check_call(['wget', '-O', directory, image])` which avoids the shell (and thus the need for quoting, as well as [a slew of other possible issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)) and gives you more control over several aspects of the behavior of the subprocess. (Better still to avoid a subprocess, too, though.)

Comment: For what it 's worth, the location of the Python script is unimportant here. See [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the package you specified has not been updated since 2015, it's repository is gone and so should probably be avoided. you can download files using the built-in `requests` module like so:

```
import requests

image_url = 'https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300'
file_destination = 'desired/destination/file.jpg'
res = requests.get(image_url)
if res.status_code == 200:  # http 200 means success
    with open(file_destination, 'wb') as file_handle:  # wb means Write Binary
        file_handle.write(res.content)
```

Comment: I tried with this method but it gives me an error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/edoardo/Documents/media/photos/photo 1.jpg' `

I imagined that it was because the file i was trying to download was empty, but with the `wget` module the file downloaded, so I don't get what's wrong

Comment: @EdoardoBalducci does this path `/Users/edoardo/Documents/media/photos` exist? `open` will not create the path if it doesn't exist, only the file

Comment: @EdoardoBalducci if you are on windows then that path is not good, absolute paths should start with a drive letter so try 'c:/Users/edoardo/Documents/media/photos/photo 1.jpg'